# modify view in django to handle ajax request

Tags: ajax, django

I have a simple problem. I have a fully functioning site in django, which has a header, menu and footer, that never changes and a content that changes. My simplified templates look like this:
base.html

```
<html>
  ...header...
  <body>
    ...menu...
    {%block content%}{%endblock%}
    ...footer...
  </body>
</html>
```

and content.html

```
{%extends 'base.html'%}
{%block content%}...content according to selected menu item...{%endblock%}
```

To this point, everything works fine.
Now I decided that for users, that have javascript enabled, I can add ajax call, so whenever they click upper menu item(will have onClick), only the "content" block is upgraded.My question is: Can I reuse my original view and modify it somehow to fit both needs-regular calls and ajax calls? Or should I somehow redesign my templates? Or do I need a separate view for each?
My simplified view looks like:

```
def main(request,site):
  ...some site processing...
  return render_to_response('content.html',{'content':...site content...})
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will be much easier to use a convenient feature of the `url` parameter in the `jquery.load()` method than to play around with the django templates and views. The [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/) sais

> The `.load()` method [...] allows us to specify a portion of
>   the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special
>   syntax for the url parameter. If one or more space characters are
>   included in the string, the portion of the string following the first
>   space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content
>   to be loaded.

In your JavaScript event handler you simply write something like this:

```
$('.content').load('/otherPage.html .content');
```

That's all.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer because it lead me to final solution. The basic idea, if you want to use ajax in your django app and don't have to type a lot of extra code for it is to think about templates in a different way. Instead of extending templates, you should include blocks you want later update via Ajax. If the request is regular you just render the base (or anything extending base), if Ajax you render just the piece, which is then placed where it should be-awesome thing is-you can do this in one view. Check [this](http://www.micahcarrick.com/ajax-form-submission-django.html)

Answer (score 0):

You may check in your view for an ajax call and give the corresponding response:

```
if request.is_ajax():
    #do something
```

Have a look here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.is_ajax

Hope this leads into the right direction.

Comment: thanks, I'm aware of that, but at this point I only need to render content.html without base.html and I really don't know how to do that without duplicating template code for content without "extends" tag

Comment: Most commonly you just return some "values" in JSON format and insert them via javascript into your website.

Comment: Is it a bad principle to return html?

Comment: No, I would not say that, you are free to return whatever you want, but in my experience it is more convinient to return some JSON formated values to manipulate the html document.

Comment: Ok, I understand that, but in this particular example, I can't send back just "values", because there's a variable content structure for each page (html in content block looks different on each page), so I need to send html

Comment: So just return the html and put it into your html document.

Comment: Yes that's what i want, but where can I get html of just "content" if the content template contains extends tag. When I call render (to_response or to_string or anything else) with content.html I always get whole site html, I hope it is explained clearer now